# VP8 video rendering in Javascript

Tags: javascript, decode, webm, vp8, libvpx

I'm currently working on a interactive web application in javascript that renders in realtime a video received on a webpage and lets you send keyboard inputs.

The fact is that I can only receive VP8 video streams (not webm, just raw VP8 video without the Matroska container). I've managed to decode the video from the client side using dixie decoder (https://github.com/dominikhlbg/vp8-webm-javascript-decoder/), but the problem is that it adds buffering or something, because there is a lag of almost 2 seconds between when I receive a stream and I render it. Is there a way I can decode the stream natively? That would speed it the performance.

I thought of adding a matroska container to the vp8 received stream and sending it to the video tag, but I don't know how to create such container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after days trying to figure out how to solve this I finally found the bug, which it wasn't in the Dixie decoder, but the server that needed a flag to stop buffering the video.